# Can't log in using wayland Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: xorg, login, wayland

I am having difficulties logging into my computer (I can ssh in to access make changes, etc). When using /etc/gdm3/custom.conf #WaylandEnable=false I can't log in.  After I enter my password, the screen briefly goes black, and then returns to the login screen.  When I remove comment to have WaylandEnable=false, I can log in, with echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE giving X11.  I don't get a gear icon in the login screen to change the session type. This arose after attempting to set up chrome remote desktop, and maybe it messed up a setting?  I ran these commands:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y xfce4 desktop-base

DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="4/stuffdeleted" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=$(hostname)

sudo bash -c 'echo "exec /etc/X11/Xsession /usr/bin/xfce4-session" > /etc/chrome-remote-desktop-session'
```

Here is my system info:
product: GP107GL [Quadro P620] [10DE:1CB6]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE]
NVIDIA Driver Version 515.65.01
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
kernel 5.15.0-47-generic
x86_64

The system was running properly for months using wayland until now. I had installed/uninstalled some vnc software and run some other commands like below before last reboot, so that may also have affected the system.

`sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind; sudo systemctl restart display-manager; loginctl terminate-user xxxx`

Update--I added another user, and in the login screen when I click on either the original user or the new user, the gear icon shows up with options for Ubuntu or Xfce session.  If I choose Ubuntu, it works as usual for either user.  Xfce session fails with original user, but works for new user.

Comment: What Ubuntu release/kernel are you using? What video hardware and what driver are you using?  All those factors affect Wayland use.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on a similar post
[Cannot login Wayland sessions on 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237050/cannot-login-wayland-sessions-on-20-04)

I moved the ~/.config folder to ~/.config.HOLD , changed /etc/gdm3/custom.conf to #WaylandEnable=false, and restarted.  I then saw an option in the gear icon for Ubuntu Wayland.  When I selected that, I could log in.  I then moved the .config folder to .config.works as a backup and replaced with the original ~/.config.HOLD.  In that .config folder, I deleted recently changed folders chrome-remote-desktop and google-chrome.  I then restarted, and my desktop and system seem to be as before, and running wayland.  It seems likely that something about chrome-remote-desktop caused problems.