# Ubuntu Wayland session won't start

Tags: gnome, amd-graphics, wayland

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 few weeks ago, and I didn't test Wayland that time. I never actually edit anything in the gdm3 configuration (only edited the wallpaper and appearance). Then I want to use Wayland to use Waydroid, but the session immediately crashed.
I checked `journalctl` and found some errors related to Wayland Session

```
gnome-shell[2248]: Added device '/dev/dri/card0' (amdgpu) using atomic mode setting.
kernel: nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: Correcting number of heads for current head configuration (0x00)
gnome-shell[2248]: Failed to initialize accelerated iGPU/dGPU framebuffer sharing: An EGLDisplay argument does not name a valid EGL display connection.
gnome-shell[2248]: Created gbm renderer for '/dev/dri/card1'
gnome-shell[2248]: Failed to detect hardware rendering: eglMakeCurrent(): An EGLDisplay argument does not name a valid EGL display connection.
gnome-shell[2248]: Failed to initialize accelerated iGPU/dGPU framebuffer sharing: Not hardware accelerated
gnome-shell[2248]: Created gbm renderer for '/dev/dri/card0'
gnome-shell[2248]: GPU /dev/dri/card1 selected as primary
gnome-shell[2248]: Failed to setup: Unable to initialize the Clutter backend: no available drivers found.
systemd[2045]: org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
systemd[2045]: Failed to start GNOME Shell on Wayland.
```

I think it's somehow related to my AMD GPU (or either NVIDIA GPU, because at the first line it shows "Added device 'dev/dri/card0' (amdgpu)), but when I try using X11 (Xorg) it was working fine. I also tried doing the solution from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237050/cannot-login-wayland-sessions-on-20-04), and it also didn't work
Anyone can help?

Comment: Add this info to the question with edit not as a comment.

Comment: Did tried editing but apparently the edit didn't apply

Answer (score 0):

Respect to Waydroid you can use it inside a Weston session according [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/qs9c9s/how_to_run_waydroid_under_xorg/), that way if Wayland fails or if you choose to going back to xorg still having a way to run it (the script needs a bit of work, I test the command manually).

Comment: Yes that works and I still use that fallback solution, but I also do want the default ubuntu (gnome) wayland to work. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I'm afraid not (personal preference of xorg) but hope others can and for that clarification its needed, I use integrated AMD with 22.04 myself and getting drivers to work was a long task, but you said that its working.

Comment: I suggest if you can add more to the question: what gpu? what installation process you follow? and what is "works" (eg. xorg load and login but wayland not )? or if you already fixed it let us know

Comment: The thing I meant "works" is the Weston session that you suggest me, and for the gpu I have integrated AMD GPU and discrete NVIDIA RTX 3050.@ltapia